# React storybook timer setInterval is not rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, timer, setinterval, storybook

I am using react and storybook to render a countdown timer, where duration is set to say `<Timer duration={5} />` in react storybook. The countdown is not updating and the console log shows out put `5`. Can anyone please see and maybe help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from "react";

export interface TimerProps {
    id?: string;
    duration: number;
}

let count = 0;
let timeID;

const Timer: React.FC<TimerProps> = ({
    id, duration
}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(duration);
    timeID = timeID ? timeID : setInterval(function (countDown, update) {
        if( countDown === 0){
            clearInterval(timeID);
        }
        console.log(countDown);

    }, 1000, count, setCount);
    return (
        <div id="timer">
            Time to price refresh - {count}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```